# In windows, standalone utility to monitor a thread's callstack?

Tags: windows, memory, callstack

Does anyone know of a program that can be used to look at the callstack/memory being used by any given Windows thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for a good Windows debugger?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most commonly used tools for such things is WinDbg. You can freely download 32-bit version from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463016.aspx) and 64-bit version from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463012.aspx). Using this tool you can attach to any Windows process from a command line `WinDbg -p <Process_ID>`

[Here](http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html) you can find a list of common WinDbg command including stack trace and different memory inspection commands. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx) you can find a WinDbg tutorial.

Hope this will help.